# Convert a Python block of code into a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, logic, converters

Below is the python block code,

```
def compute_hcf(x, y):
   while(y):
       x, y = y, x % y
   return x
```

which I wanted to convert into single line like below,

```
def compute_hcf(x, y):\n\t while(y): \n\t\t x, y = y, x % y \n\t return x
```

I've the below approach to solve this,

```
def convert(fname):
    newLines = ''
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            num_spaces = 0
            
            for letter in line:
                if letter != ' ':
                    break
                num_spaces += 1

            if num_spaces == 3:
                line = line.replace(' '*3, '\\t') #If number of Spaces is 3, replace with a single tab
            elif num_spaces == 4:
                line = line.replace(' '*4, '\\t') #If number of Spaces is 4, replace with a single tab
            elif num_spaces == 7:
                line = line.replace(' ' *7, '\\t\\t') #If number of Spaces is 7, replace with double tab
            elif num_spaces == 8:
                line = line.replace(' ' * 8, '\\t\\t') #If number of Spaces is 8, replace with double tab
            line = line + '\\n' #Adding new line at the end of the line
            newLines = newLines + line
    converted = ''.join(newLines)
    print(converted)
    
convert('fileWithInputContent.txt')
```

Actual Output:

```
def compute_hcf(x, y):
\n\twhile(y):
\n\t\tx, y = y, x % y
\n\treturn x\n
```

Expected Output:

```
def compute_hcf(x, y):\n\t while(y): \n\t\t x, y = y, x % y \n\t return x
```

Comment: May I ask *why* you are trying to do this? Probably, you just need `result = repr(f.read())`

Comment: I needed this to maintain it as a Target attribute for my dataset. Thanks it helped

Comment: `result = repr(f.read())` is handling only the '\n' . Can you please tell me how to handle the tabs - '\t'

Answer (score 0):

When you read text from a file in python, there is automatically a newline character added to the end of each line. So when we print out the strings that python reads it looks like this.

[image showing that there is a newline character at the end of the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWQj4.png)

This is why the actual output has newlines. So in order to fix this, we just need to remove the newline character with something like this.

```
if '\n' in line:
     line = line.replace('\n', '')
```

The code with this addition looks like this.

```
def convert(fname):
newLines = ''
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # print each string
        # print(repr(line))
        if '\n' in line:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
        num_spaces = 0
        
        for letter in line:
            if letter != ' ':
                break
            num_spaces += 1

        if num_spaces == 3:
            line = line.replace(' '*3, '\\t') #If number of Spaces is 3, replace with a single tab
        elif num_spaces == 4:
            line = line.replace(' '*4, '\\t') #If number of Spaces is 4, replace with a single tab
        elif num_spaces == 7:
            line = line.replace(' ' *7, '\\t\\t') #If number of Spaces is 7, replace with double tab
        elif num_spaces == 8:
            line = line.replace(' ' * 8, '\\t\\t') #If number of Spaces is 8, replace with double tab
        line = line + '\\n' #Adding new line at the end of the line
        newLines = newLines + line
        
converted = ''.join(newLines)
print(converted)
```

And it works!

```
def compute_hcf(x, y):\n\twhile(y):\n\t\tx, y = y, x % y\n\treturn x\n
```